# NSString stringWithContentsOfURL returning nil when URL is retrieved from NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, macos-high-sierra

I've run into an 'interesting' (or very frustrating) problem. I need to import a file, and to prevent having to choose the same file name over and over again, I allow the user to store the name as 'default'. This name is stored in NSUserDefaults. Nothing weird here.

But, if I restart the program, the NSURL appears to be retrieved properly (I checked using NSLog AND `isEqualtTo`), but [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL] returns nil (fileExistsAtPath returns false as well). But, if I manually select the same file, it loads without problem.

So, apparently the URL retrieved from NSUserDefaults is somehow changed, even though it looks completely the same in NSLog...
The following line is the line that returns nil when fileName is filled from NSUserDefaults:

```
NSString* fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:fileName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

This is how the URL is stored in NSUserDefaults:

```
defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([specialtyFileName isNotEqualTo:nil]) {
    [defaults setURL:specialtyFileName forKey:@"SpecialtyFile"];
}
[defaults synchronize]
```

And this is how I retrieve it:

```
specialtyFileName = [defaults URLForKey:@"SpecialtyFile"];
```

The file that I test with are local files, so connection problems shouldn't be an issue. I'm a bit at a loss. Am I storing them wrong? Or retrieving? Should I preparse the URL somehow? I can't find anything on this.

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
I’m working on OSX, not on a mobile device. Also, The file that I’m using is not in any specific app-related path. Could it be that it is not allowed to acces something outside your own sandbox, unless specifically chosen by the user through a Dialogbox?

Joris

Comment: Where are the files stored? In your app's Documents folder?

Comment: As a test to make sure the URL isn't getting mangled somehow add a check right after you sync the defaults. Read the value right back out of the defaults into another variable (like `readURL`). Do a comparison between the URLs in code to make sure nothing was lost or altered.

Comment: @rmaddy: They are in a subfolder of my own projects folder, not of the App itself.

Comment: Your app can only access files that are packaged in the app's bundle or files you have stored at runtime within the app's sandbox (such as the Documents folder).

Comment: @theMikeSwan: I did that. As far as I can tell, they are identical (with NSLog; there are nog spaces or weird characters in them).

Comment: @rmaddy: also in OSX? (I forgot to mention that, sorry) Why can I select the file without problem? It only doesn't work when the URL comes from NSUserDefaults. Does it test on that then?

Comment: I don't mean look at the strings to see if they _look_ alike, use `isEqualTo:` to let the computer tell you if they are the same.

Comment: @theMikeSwan: good point. I checked, `isEqualTo:` returns true...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective C - writeToFile successful but removeFile returns error for same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47765940/objective-c-writetofile-successful-but-removefile-returns-error-for-same-file)

Comment: There is any specific reason for storing the URL (NSURL) instead of the URL path (NSString)? Maybe that can solve your issue.